# ExecCommand CreateLink and IMG

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, webbrowser-control, mshtml, execcommand

I use webbrowser-control (MSHTML Edit) in design mode. When I try to insert a hyperlink for a selected text it works fine. But when I try to insert a hyperlink for a selected picture I got the error:

```
Error 100
Function expected
```

Code:

```
var
 pCmd : OleVariant;
begin
 html_doc.execCommand('CreateLink', True, pCmd);
end;
```

How to insert a hyperlink in a picture in another way, different from using execCommand?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Works fine. What is html_doc? IHTMLdocument2?

Comment: Yes, html_doc is a IHTMLdocument2.

Comment: I have the same problem, no solution so far !

Comment: Did you try it without the dialog e.g.`html_doc..execCommand('CreateLink', false, 'http://www.example.com');`

Comment: The above solution worked for me ! :)